# Notes lost on iCloud

Tags: icloud, notes.app

Took my iPad & iPhone to Apple Store for numerous problems. They backed both up to the cloud, showed me everything was there; including my notes which are my entire business. I make organic soaps & more, hundreds of recipes, ideas, notes, research, etc. I saw them on their Mac on the iCloud before allowing them to do a system restore. Now my notes cannot be found & they will not return my calls. My business will be greatly impacted without these. I'm heartbroken. The person who assisted me at the store had made a comment saying if this didn't work I could take it somewhere they could extract the notes from the iPad for a couple hundred bucks. Please any help would be most appreciated. I'm recovering from surgery & on disability & cannot afford a couple hundred bucks right now. Thank you very much. Lee

Comment: Have you tried [iCloud.com](https://www.icloud.com/), then checking Notes there?  Otherwise, is there any chance you made a backup of your iPad and iPhone at any time?